# "find" command and piping its output through another program

Tags: command-line

this is not an Ubuntu specific quesion, it applies to all unix/linux.

how can I run a command like this:

```
 find .  -maxdepth 1 -type d  -print -exec svn info "{}"   | grep URL  \;
```

the command above doesn't do what I want, I can't seem to pipe the output of the svn info to grep.

This works, but the output contains much more than I need:

```
 find .  -maxdepth 1 -type d  -print -exec svn info "{}"  \;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please describe what you really want ? Also please put the real question (related to your objective) in the title :)

Answer (score 5):

Generally, I find `xargs` much more sane to use than find's -exec option. This is especially true for speeding things up since a separate "svn" is not started for every line of find's output:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs svn info | grep URL
```

If you're dealing with files with strange names (spaces, newlines, etc), just add `-print0` to find and `-0` to xargs:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 svn info | grep URL
```

If you're dealing with a program that can only take 1 argument, you can use `-n1` with xargs:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 svn info | grep URL
```

Comment: If you use `-exec ... +` instead of `-exec ... ";"` you gain the parallel invocation like with xargs, without -print0 gymnastics. You don't need to mask `{}` in find either, not for a current shell.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I figured out that the below does what I want in this instance:

```
  find .  -maxdepth 1 -type d  -print -exec svn info "{}"   \;  | grep URL
```

but I still would like to know how can I pipe output inside the exec of find

Comment: The following should do it: -exec sh -c "ls {} | something" \;

Comment: @João Pinto: No, you shouldn't embed `{}` into the script like that. Pass it as an argument instead. `-exec sh -c 'ls "$@" | something' _ {} \;`

Comment: You shouldn't invoke the shell at all. Charbels solution is so much better - lean and clean. What do you like to reach with your shell? Charbel just can drop the useless maskerading of `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a shell to interpret the pipe.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print -exec sh -c 'LANG=C svn info "$1" | grep URL' _ {} \;
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind for more examples.

Though. I'd just use a for-loop for that instead:

```
for svndir in ./*/.svn/; do
    dir=${svndir%/.svn/}
    echo "$dir"
    LANG=C svn info "$dir" | grep URL
    # or maybe just: sed '5!d;q' "$svndir/entries"
done
```

Comment: find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print -exec sh -c 'LANG=C svn info "$1" | grep URL'   gives me the following error: "find: missing arguments to `-exec'"

Comment: @Charbel you're missing the last part, you need to scroll right so you get the `_ {} \;` part too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -type d  -print -exec svn info "{}" \; | grep URL
```

Comment: Nearly the same as Charbel. You too may omit the maskerading of `{}`.